# SQL loop in R with rjdbc, parameterized query errors

Tags: sql, r, rjdbc

I often run sql queries through R, and I've been working on getting a particular query to work.  I provided quite a bit of info about [it here in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76239345/use-r-to-loop-through-sql-query-replacing-a-variable-each-time).

Long story short, I have a data frame I'd already pulled in, and I'm trying to loop through a sql query for each line of the dataframe I have. I'm running into some errors and it seems like (per the comments) that it may be rjdbc related. So I started a new question to deal specifically with the rjdbc errors. Here's my code:

```
library(RJDBC)   ## 

#create file path specific to the user
classpath_name="A:/ojdbc8.jar"

# Create connection driver and open connection
jdbcDriver <- JDBC(driverClass="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver", classPath=classpath_name)  ## jar8 file supplied by company for connecting to the database. (2 other jar file options)
jdbcConnection <- dbConnect(jdbcDriver, "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=lhs-dbprod.forteresearchapps.com)(PORT=2879))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=pdblhs)))", "database", "adfhkjsdabfiewubbksdjblablablabla")  ## DB hostname etc


Contacts<- dbGetQuery(jdbcConnection, 
                      "select contact_id, username from lhs_oncore_prod.rv_contact where not username='barcode_user'") 



(qmarks <- paste(rep("?", nrow(Contacts)), collapse = ","))


Access <- dbGetQuery(jdbcConnection,
                 paste("SELECT priv_check.contact_id, priv_check.protocol_id
     FROM LHS_ONCORE_PROD.sv_user_pcl_permission priv_check
     WHERE priv_check.function_name = 'CRPT-Subject Visits'
     AND priv_check.contact_id in (", qmarks, ")"),
                 params = as.list(Contacts$CONTACT_ID) )
```

And here's the errors I run into:

[image]

Based on some comments in the other thread I tried this:

```
Access <- do.call(dbGetQuery, c(list(jdbcConnection, "SELECT priv_check.contact_id, priv_check.protocol_id FROM LHS_ONCORE_PROD.sv_user_pcl_permission priv_check WHERE priv_check.function_name = 'CRPT-Subject Visits' AND priv_check.contact_id in (", qmarks, ")"), params = as.list(Contacts$CONTACT_ID) ))
```

but that returned this:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Do I see correctly ... your `Contacts` has 497 rows? Yeah ... you should _really_ be using the other method I suggested in the previous question: upload to a temp table, query on a join. If you have confirmed that you are not permitted even _temporary_ tables, then I suggest you re-attempt this with only 10 or so rows to confirm if the method even works as expected; if it does, then perhaps there is a limit for how many parameters you can bind to the query.

Comment: Thank you for staying with this.  Because of your comment, it got me thinking:   I was just about to dive back into whether or not I'm allowed to do a temporary table, but I wonder...

the contacts just come from the same database.  As you can see, like a line above, I just pull from rv_contact.   Given I'm downloading it a second prior, rather than push it back up in, there's gotta be a different way.

Comment: For the record it does seem like I'm not allowed either way.  Tried dbwritetable and got the error:   insufficient privileges

Comment: Assuming you tried with `temporary=TRUE`?

Comment: Looks like you can combine the queries into a single query to pull all data at once.

Comment: Yup!  Just did it.  Lol now I dont know what to do about this question above.  Cant decide whether to delete or leave it

Comment: since it's so data-specific, I don't know that self-answering it is going to help a lot of other people, but over to you